# How to register polly in startup file in .net core 2.2?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core-2.1, circuit-breaker, polly

I am implementing polly in my .net core 2.2 application. For HttpClient there is a nuget Microsoft.Extenstions.Http.Polly which can to used to register any polly pattern (circuit breaker or retry) in startup. But how can I used polly for other exceptions like "SqlException". 
Just take an example of this chunk:

```
        Policy
        .Handle<SqlException>(ex => ex.Number == (int)SqlHandledExceptions.DatabaseNotCurrentlyAvailable)
        .CircuitBreakerAsync(
            // number of exceptions before breaking circuit
            exceptionsAllowedBeforeBreaking,
            // time circuit opened before retry
            TimeSpan.FromSeconds(30),
            OnBreak,
            OnReset,
            OnHalfOpen)
        .WithPolicyKey($"F1.{PolicyKeys.SqlCircuitBreakerAsyncPolicy}"),
```

I want to register this policy in startup file to handle sql exception. How can I do this?

Answer (score 3):

Polly provides the concept of a [PolicyRegistry](https://github.com/App-vNext/Polly/wiki/PolicyRegistry) for maintaining a collection of policies.

For policies not directly connected with http calls, a recommended DI approach is to [register a PolicyRegistry with DI](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.extensions.dependencyinjection.pollyservicecollectionextensions.addpolicyregistry?view=aspnetcore-2.2) during `StartUp` and populate that registry with policies, also during the `StartUp` phase.

Code consuming the policies can then simply take an `IReadOnlyPolicyRegistry` by DI, and retrieve the appropriate policy from the registry, using [the patterns shown in the Polly documentation](https://github.com/App-vNext/Polly/wiki/PolicyRegistry#populate-a-registry-with-policies).

---

(For completeness of information: the `PolicyRegistry` approach [can also be used with HttpClientFactory and HttpClient](https://github.com/App-vNext/Polly/wiki/Polly-and-HttpClientFactory#selecting-policies-from-a-policyregistry).)

Answer (score 2):

You can't, per se. There's nothing to "register"; the policy just is. The `IHttpClientFactory` Polly integration is specific to `IHttpClientFactory`, and under the hood just wraps the Polly policies around the `HttpMessageHandler`.

Typically, you'd just define your Polly policies in line with whatever code you're handling. If you're looking for a way to have a shared reusable policy, just create a halper class or something and store it there.

Comment: So means in case of sql. i need to call the chunk on every place where i am querying database?

Comment: Polly provides a ready-made class for storing policies: PolicyRegistry (see answer below)